# creating a horizontal card scroll with an highlighted card

Tags: angular, html, css

I wish to create a horizontal scroll of cards (imagine a set of 10 cards where only 3 of them are showed at a time and the rest are shown when its scrolled horizontally).
I wish to highlight the middle card while keeping the other cards blurred a little so that these cards are scrolled but the user is made to see the middle highlighted card.
The scroll is to be designed in such a way that when user scrolls it gets scrolled by a specific length keeping the highlighted card in the middle.

An approach that i thought of was to create three horizontal divs and then the cards overlapping these divs, these cards are rendered from the angular using databinding.
Now i scrolled these cards along the div, sadly i couldn't make it work as i had no idea how to achieve this either.

Comment: Can you post the code showing what you have tried so far? StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Try to attach at least some image, code or wireframe so, it will help us what you need exactly